# Flutter stream value is not null while transformation should make it null when error happens

Tags: flutter, dart, stream, rxdart

Have a Stream which can be incorrect therefor i will sink add null in it during the transform.
But the transformation change doesnt affect the BehaviourSubject.value nor BehaviourSubject.stream.value

```
BehaviorSubject _roomAmount  = BehaviorSubject<String>();
Stream<String> get roomAmount$  => _roomAmount.stream.transform(validateRoomsAmount); 

final validateRoomsAmount = StreamTransformer<String, String>.fromHandlers(
    handleData: (value, sink){
      //Add null before
      sink.add(null);
      if(value == null || value == '') {
        return;
      }
      //when it is wrong add error and return
      if(value.length > 9) {
        sink.addError("Too long");
        return;
      }
      //when it is right add value into sink
      sink.add(size.toString());
);

House getHouse() {
  //_roomAmount.value returns the value which has a length over 9, which should have been transformed to null
  return House(roomAmount: _roomAmount.value);
}
```

When I create an object from my stream it has the wrong value in it. Apperantly it doesn't seem to interesst that the value was sinked as null in the transform function. 
I think i dont fully understand how I should create an object from BehaviourSubject. 
When I type transformation function gets called with each sign. 
Stream displayes error correctly has a data of null, which is also expected behaviour. 
Only when i am about to create an object out of the stream it is the unexpected value.

I use
rxdart: 0.24.1

flutter doctor -v

[√] Flutter (Channel unknown, 1.26.0-17.8.pre, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1706], locale de-DE) 
• Flutter version 1.26.0-17.8.pre at c:\flutter 
• Framework revision 044f2cf560 (1 year, 3 months ago), 2021-02-24 13:02:05 -0800 
• Engine revision 042c82b02c 
• Dart version 2.12.0 (build 2.12.0-259.16.beta)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using `flatMap` and `where` to achieve that without the need to transformation which makes your code readability very difficult.

try this:

```
  final _roomAmount = BehaviorSubject<String>();

  Stream<String> get roomAmount => _roomAmount.stream
          .where((value) => !value.isNullOrBlank)
          .flatMap((value) {
        if (value.length > 9) return Stream.error("Too long");
        return Stream.value(value);
      });
```

`where`: ensures your stream will receive only non null or blank text.

`flatMap`: checks the length and return error or value.

Comment: The error is still the same as descirbed above. The _roomAmount.value returns the "too long" value